# Why android.app.Activity.onTrimMemory couldn't be overridden?

Tags: android, eclipse

Good afternoon all,

I was wondering why is it that [android.app.Activity.onTrimMemory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29) couldn't be overridden?

[image]

Does anyone know how can we fix the problem?

Comment: Are you sure your Eclipse project is using the right version of the Android SDK? It looks like it's using an SDK level before 14 (at which point that method didn't exist, which is why Eclipse is complaining about the `@Override` annotation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method was added in API Level 14. Your build target is an API level less than 14. Hence, the method does not exist, and you cannot override it.

Comment: Are you aware of an alternative solution for this functionality in versions before 14?

Comment: @Pacerier: If by "this functionality" you mean "Android tapping you on the shoulder and telling you when you might consider freeing some memory", no. However, you know when an activity is going into the background courtesy of methods like `onPause()` and `onUserLeaveHint()`, so you can trim memory then. Or, use things like `SoftReference` in your caches, so the Dalvik VM will automatically free memory as needed.

Comment: Before API 14 it was onLowMemory and it was the equivalent to onTrimMemory with level = 80 (TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE)